# Manage containerd with Ansible

Tags: ansible, containerd

Is there any way to manage `containerd`, containers, and container images with native Ansible modules? Attempts with the Ansible Docker modules failed:

```yaml
- name: "Obtain list of containers"
  community.docker.docker_host_info:
    docker_host: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
    debug: true
    containers: true
    containers_all: true
  register: containers
```

yields the error message

```
Error connecting: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

A Google search revealed no native Ansible modules for managing containerd.

Are there any options to manage containerd directly from Ansible besides invoking `nerdctl` directly or implementing myself?

Answer (score -1):

You can use podman which relies on runc (containerd also relies on runc).

Then use the official module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/containers/podman/podman_container_module.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I have asked for. I want to stick with containerd and not switch to Podman.